# error 503 centreon how can redirect properly this

Tags: debian, apache2, port, http-status-code-503

when I try to connect with my address `172.16.16.170:5000` here is the page I get and I don’t know how to fix, it i thinks it's a error of config but i don't now where. i configure port in apache2 and now a page apear but steal not working, i restart apache2 and centreon services and i reboot my server

[image: web site centreon]

ask me if u want more info i don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are at the very first steps of your Centreon 19.04.01 installation with Debian 9, you may check the different actions hereafter and check what can be missing with yours.

```
> groupadd -g 6000 centreon useradd -u 6000 -g centreon -m -r -d
> /var/lib/centreon -c "Centreon Admin" -s /bin/bash centreon
> usermod -aG centreon centreon-broker
```

You need PHP 7.1 with recent releases of Centreon.

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates -y
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-opcache libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-json php7.1-gd php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-intl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xml php7.1-zip php7.1-fpm php7.1-readline -y
```

You need more packages for Debian 9, and Centreon team suggests MariaDB database.

```
apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3 php-pear sudo tofrodos bsd-mailx lsb-release mariadb-server libconfig-inifiles-perl libcrypt-des-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libdigest-sha-perl libgd-perl php7.1-ldap php7.1-snmp php-db php-date -y
```

Modules activation

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif proxy rewrite
a2enconf php7.1-fpm
a2dismod php7.1
systemctl restart apache2 php7.1-fpm
```

Date Timezone is now mandatory during Centreon setup.

```
vi /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Toronto
```

Install PHP Composer

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

Install Javascript dependencies

```
apt-get install curl
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
npm install
npm run build
```

And it should be good to launch your Centreon installation with **install.sh** script.

After that, before trying to reach the Web frontend, you have to allow Centreon configuration for your Apache Web server.

```
a2enconf centreon.conf
```

It is advised to separate Centreon log files from others.

```
vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/centreon.conf
```

Add those two lines after Directory directive.

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.centreon.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.centreon.log combined
```

After Apache restart, two separate log files are now created.

```
ls -l /var/log/apache2/*.centreon.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 janv. 30 17:39 /var/log/apache2/access.centreon.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 243 janv. 30 17:39 /var/log/apache2/error.centreon.log
```

Restart the conf

```
systemctl restart apache2 php7.1-fpm
```

And then try again to reach your Centreon URL